Index of a nowhere vanishing vector field.
Let $M$ be a closed (smooth) manifold. For a (smooth) vector field $X$ on $M$ with only isolated zeros $\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}=X^{-1}\{0\}$, we define the $\text{Index}(X)=\sum_{p\in X^{-1}\{0\}}\iota(V,p)$, where $\iota$ denotes the local index. What if $V$ vanished nowhere? Would this formula still stand where the empty sum would be zero?
For example there is a theorem that if $X$ is a vector field with only isolated singularities, there exist a vector field $\tilde X$ with only isolated non degenerate singularities with $\text{Index}(X)=\text{Index}(\tilde X)$. I think I have noticed that with methods of replacing non degenerate zeros you might end up with a vector field with no singularities.

Yes in that case the sum is zero.
